# Deletion with on restrict constraint postgres

Tags: postgresql, constraints

Is it possible to delete the row "on cascade" in postgres if there is a restrict constraint?
And is it possible to change all restrict constraints to cascade constraints automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither is possible. Your options would be to:

- `DROP CONSTRAINT`, `DELETE` and `ADD CONSTRAINT`

or

- `DROP CONSTRAINT`, `ADD CONSTRAINT ... ON DELETE CASCADE` and `DELETE`

From PostgreSQL Documentation you can see what alterations can be done on table constraints:
[I. SQL Commands - ALTER TABLE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-altertable.html)